# One-click save to Downloads folder in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app

When I click on an attachment in Mail.app, the file opens in the mail downloads in my library. I can Ctrl-click on the attachment to save it to my Downloads folder. How can I save the file to the Downloads folder in one click?

I'm using 10.8.

Comment: I don't think what your asking is possible however as a workaround you could set a Rule that saves attachments to wherever you want via AppleScript.  Have a look at: [Automatically Save Attachments in Mail.app](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/automatically-save-attachments-in-mail-app/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is directly possible. However, you can right-click on the attachment and select "Save to Downloads folder".